# How to identify SOME/IP PDU in arxml file?

Tags: autosar

If I have arxml file with a Ethernet Cluster define in it.Then how to find out if it has SOME/IP PDU in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look for an `ISignalIPdu` where an `ISignal` is mapped to it and the `ISignal` aggregates a `SOMEIPTransformationISignalProps` that in turn references a `SOMEIPTransformationDescription` that fulfills constr_3128 in the role `transformer`.

Comment: Thanks for replay. so in this case is it possible to have more than one ISignal mapped to ISignalIPdu

Comment: If  "DISCOVERY-TECHNOLOGY" or "REMOTING-TECHNOLOGY" or "SERIALIZATION-TECHNOLOGY-REF" attribute of ApplicationEndpoint set to SOME/IP. Does that mean All PDU send/receive by this ApplicationEndpoint is SOME/IP.

Comment: can you please comment on my above question?

Comment: @HarshaJumde Most use cases foresee only a single ISignal per Pdu.